# Debugging Arrays with echo (Php)

Tags: php

I've a week off work so I'm keeping busy trying to learn php.

I want to check the contents of my array by printing out whats contrained in them.

```
    foreach ($articleList as $item)
    {
        $this->articles[] = array(
                                    'url' => $this->domain . $item->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href'),
                'title' => $item->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    //                              'author' => $item->getElementsByTagName('em')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'description' => $item->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'article' => ''
                                );
}

    foreach ($this->articles as $x)
    {
        echo $x;
    }
```

The code at the bottom is where I am trying to print out each piece of the array and see what contents it holds, So i can understand what the code above it is doing.

But its just blank even though the array size is 30.

How can I go about doing this?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to output an array to check its contents.

Try just doing:

```
print_r($this);
```

...instead of the second loop.

It also shows the position of items in an array.

Answer (score 1):

In your `foreach` loop, each element is itself an array.

Try `print_r($x);` instead of `echo $x;`

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy is just to do a var_dump. 
`var_dump($x);`

Answer (score 0):

Each item in your articles array is also an array, so you're likely seeing `Array` when you echo out each one.

You will need to dive into each array in your articles array:

```
foreach ($this->articles as $x)
{
   print_r($x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($articleList as $item)
{
    $this->articles[] = array(
                                'url' => $this->domain . $item->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href'),
            'title' => $item->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue,
//                              'author' => $item->getElementsByTagName('em')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'description' => $item->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'article' => ''
                            );
}

print_r($this->articles);

or

var_dump($this->articles)
```